Split long rows of a column vector to make it fit on the page
I have a large matrix -- a column vector, actually -- which doesn't fit on a page. I would like to split the matrix to fit on the page, Can someone help me with how I can do that? Any help is greatly appreciated!.


you should show the code, but in each cell, replace \frac{}{}[.......]  by \begin{aligned} \frac{}...\\....\end{aligned} splitting the line at a suitable place.

I suppose that some subjectivity is unavoidable regarding the choices of line break points and indentation amounts.

\documentclass{article} % Or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % Set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{amsmath} % For '\DeclareMathOperator', '\tfrac', and '\jot' macros
                     % and for 'aligned' and 'pmatrix' environments
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectations operator
% \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Optional (Times Roman text and math fonts).

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\E(S_N^5) =  % <-- don't auto-size these parentheses
\begin{pmatrix}
    \begin{aligned}
       \tfrac{\lambda\alpha_1^{}\beta_1^5}{1-\exp(-\lambda)} \bigl\{
       & (\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_1+2) [ (\alpha_1+3)(\alpha_1+4) 
         +5\lambda\alpha_1(\alpha_1+3) +10\lambda\alpha_1 (\alpha_1+1) \\
       & +10\lambda^2\alpha_1^2 ] +15\lambda^2\alpha_1^2(\alpha_1+1)^2 
         +10\lambda^3\alpha_1^3(\alpha_1+1) + \lambda^4\alpha_1^4 \bigr\} 
       \\[\jot]
       \tfrac{\lambda\alpha_2^{}\beta_2^5}{1-\exp(-\lambda)} \bigl\{
       & (\alpha_2+1)(\alpha_2+2) [ (\alpha_2+3)(\alpha_2+4) 
         +5\lambda\alpha_2(\alpha_2+3) +10\lambda\alpha_2 (\alpha_2+1) \\
       & +10\lambda^2\alpha_2^2 ] +15\lambda^2\alpha_2^2(\alpha_2+1)^2 
         +10\lambda^3\alpha_2^3(\alpha_2+1) + \lambda^4\alpha_2^4 \bigr\}
    \end{aligned}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


Addendum: If the text block were any narrower and/or the font size were a bit larger than in the preceding solution (where the text block width was 6.5 inches and the main font size was 10pt), it would be necessary to insert two line breaks in each element of the column vector.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
%\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{amsmath} % For '\DeclareMathOperator', '\tfrac', and '\jot' macros
                     % and for 'aligned' and 'pmatrix' environments
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectations operator
% \usepackage{newtx} % optional: Times Roman text and math fonts

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\E(S_N^5) =  % <-- don't auto-size these parentheses
\begin{pmatrix}
   \begin{aligned}
      &\smash[b]{\tfrac%
        {\lambda\alpha_1^{}\beta_1^5}{1-\exp(-\lambda)}} 
        \bigl\{ (\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_1+2) 
        \bigl[  (\alpha_1+3)(\alpha_1+4) \\
      &\quad +5\lambda\alpha_1(\alpha_1+3) 
        +10\lambda\alpha_1 (\alpha_1+1) 
        +10\lambda^2\alpha_1^2 \bigr]\\ 
      &\quad +15\lambda^2\alpha_1^2(\alpha_1+1)^2 
        +10\lambda^3\alpha_1^3(\alpha_1+1) 
        +\lambda^4\alpha_1^4 \bigr\} 
      \\[\jot]
      &\smash[b]{\tfrac%
        {\lambda\alpha_2^{}\beta_2^5}{1-\exp(-\lambda)}} 
        \bigl\{ (\alpha_2+1)(\alpha_2+2) 
        \bigl[  (\alpha_2+3)(\alpha_2+4) \\ 
      &\quad +5\lambda\alpha_2(\alpha_2+3) 
        +10\lambda\alpha_2 (\alpha_2+1)
        +10\lambda^2\alpha_2^2 \bigr] \\
      &\quad +15\lambda^2\alpha_2^2(\alpha_2+1)^2 
        +10\lambda^3\alpha_2^3(\alpha_2+1) 
        +\lambda^4\alpha_2^4 \bigr\}
   \end{aligned}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


Thank you, I appreciate that.
